# how can I create a for loop to select columns with specific data and linking it to a summary sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to loop through the columns from test sheet for specific data and copying it to a summary sheet. The data copied should be linked to the test sheet. So, if I made changes to the test sheet it will reflect on the summary sheet and if I were to add data, it will add it to the summary sheet when I execute the macro using VBA.

Example, the test sheet has systems, id, location, project id, tag data, but I only want to copy the data systems, id and location to the summary sheet. And if I were to add a new system, when I execute the macro, it will generate it to the summary sheet that's why I think I will need to use the for loop.

Currently this is what I have

```
Sub test()
' test Macro
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, i As Long

    ' Initial cell to check
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    Set Rng1 = WS1.Range("B1")

    ' Initial cell to store
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set Rng2 = WS2.Range("A2")

    ' Clear original data on Summary
    i = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng2.Offset(i, 0))
        Rng2.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng1)
        If Rng1.Value = 1 Then
            Rng2.Value = Rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value ' Description
            Rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value = Rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value ' Nominal
            Rng2.Offset(0, 2).Value = Rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value ' Max
            Set Rng2 = Rng2.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to store
        End If
        Set Rng1 = Rng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    Set Rng1 = Nothing
    Set WS1 = Nothing
    Set Rng2 = Nothing
    Set WS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more info than that my friend.

Comment: Some code (even a recorded macro) with a [mcve] to show how far you got and what doesn't work, even a picture would help. As is I dont think you'll get a good answer... please [edit] it. FYI I asked [so]'s AI and its a good start for what to try: https://stackoverflow.com/ai/search/35234

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, still new around this platform, not sure how I can upload a picture of the excel sheet to show the issue I have but that's the start of the code I got through this platform that is the closest to what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you have to set the Summary sheet cells' content with a formula which refers to the source sheet's cells (Test sheet).

```
Sub test()
' test Macro
    Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Dim WS1 As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet, i As Long

    ' Initial cell to check
    Set WS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
    Set Rng1 = WS1.Range("B1")

    ' Initial cell to store
    Set WS2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
    Set Rng2 = WS2.Range("A2")

    ' Clear original data on Summary
    i = 0
    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng2.Offset(i, 0))
        Rng2.Offset(i, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    Do Until IsEmpty(Rng1)
        If Rng1.Value = 1 Then
            'three lines edited
            Rng2.Formula = "=Test!" & Rng1.Offset(0, 2).Address ' Description
            Rng2.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=Test!" & Rng1.Offset(0, 2).Address ' Nominal
            Rng2.Offset(0, 2).Formula = "=Test!" & Rng1.Offset(0, 1).Address ' Max
            Set Rng2 = Rng2.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to store
        End If
        Set Rng1 = Rng1.Offset(1, 0) ' Move to next row to check
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    Set Rng1 = Nothing
    Set WS1 = Nothing
    Set Rng2 = Nothing
    Set WS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```